# Motorola MC3190 emulator

Tags: .net, mobile

Is there emulator of Motorola MC3190 so I can run and debug application from visual studio?
I have 2 devices where windows not loading. If there are no emulators any help with reinstalling windows on device will be great.

Comment: Can you clarify as to whether you mean Windows CE or Windows Mobile.

Comment: Its Windows Mobile 6. But emulator of Windows Mobile is not enough, because I need emulation of RFID reader to debug my app.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I request you that before posting a question directly here try to Google it from your side and share your search result

Comment: Nothing about emulators or reinstalling windows in google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is no way to reinstall windows, only Motorola can do it. To debug my application I have wrote fake Barcode and RFID readers so now I can debug it on the emulator.

Answer (score -1):

A quick Google search results in:

[EMDK for .NET v2.4](http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=12874&sliceId=&dialogID=216706471&stateId=1%200%20216708097)

Which appears to have RFID stuff in it - does that help?

Comment: No, it does not help, I have newer version already installed, but there are no emulators.